# 1password asks me for the 2FA at every startup

Tags: gnome

this is my first post :)

As per the subject, 1password is asking me for 2FA at every startup. I found this [guide](https://1password.community/discussion/115935/1password-for-linux-2fa-faq) , but I already have the checkmark enabled for "Read, add, change, or remove saved passwords"

Advice on how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].